# Trigger Azure DevOps CI using continuous integration

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I need assistance on how to trigger a particular CI when we have multiple projects in one branch.

In my case - I have one project, in the project I have one repository, inside the repository I have one branch, inside the branch I have multiple projects (.CSPROJ) and one solution file(.SLN). If there is a change in project A my CI should get trigger only for that particular project. The other CI which is referring to Project B should not get trigger which is in the same branch.

Pleas assist on this request.

Comment: Just create several pipelines with different path triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the trigger official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths

Such as:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - some/path/1/*
```

and

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - some/path/2/*
```